# Is there a way to fill blank cell with zeroes in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

everyone!

I would like to create a script which could **substitute every blank cell in a defined range** with a 0 after I run it.

Is this possible?

For example, if I had this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 4 |  |
| 2 | 5 |
|  |  |
|  | 8 |

I would like to end with this output:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 8 |

Thanks!

I have tried to tinkle with multiples script formulas, but so far, it has been a titanic task to find one which recognizes the blank values and swaps them for a numeric value.

Comment: Try setting the number format to `0.#########`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn())
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  const row = rg.getRow();
  const col = rg.getColumn();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    r.forEach((c,j) => {
      if(c === '') {
        sh.getRange(i + row, j + col).setNumberFormat("0.###########").setValue(0)
      }
    })
  })
}
```